# How do you determine which type of Mob you have selected?

Tags: rift

How can you tell the difference between the mobs in Rift?  Basically, if I click the mob, what is the indicator that it is not a normal mob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If it's an elite mob, it has spikes around the portrait when you target it.
- If it's a rare mob, it has a diamond in the portrait.
- Boss mobs have a red skull where the level would be as well